# Getting Text from BodytPart when IsHTML=True from an Outlook 2016 Encoded HTML

Tags: c#, mailkit

HTML Messages sent from Outlook 2010 arrive in message.TextBody just fine.
I'm finding, however, that messages originating from Outlook 2016 are not.  The TextBody is null.  The message is in the HtmlBody.

How can I extract the text of the message?  I've tried using

```
 System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Regex.Replace(htmlContent, "<(.|\n)*?>", ""))
```

but it's only cleaning up some but not all of the Office:Word styles mess.

(I can't seem to copy the HTML so I hope you know what it looks like.)

I'm using MailKit in a VB.net application.

Comment: Had the same issue when the mail html encoding wasn't Utf8. Solution by @jstedfast below worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

MailKit depends on MimeKit which has an HTML tokenizer in the `MimeKit.Text` namespace.

You can use that to remove html tokens and leave just the character data.

```
using (var writer = new StringWriter ()) {
    using (var reader = new StringReader (html)) {
        var tokenizer = new HtmlTokenizer (reader) {
            DecodeCharacterReferences = true
        };
        HtmlToken token;

        while (tokenizer.ReadNextToken (out token)) {
            switch (token.Kind) {
            case HtmlTokenKind.Data:
                var data = (HtmlDataToken) token;
                writer.Write (data.Data);
                break;
            case HtmlTokenKind.Tag:
                var tag = (HtmlTagToken) token;
                switch (tag.Id) {
                case HtmlTagId.Br:
                    writer.Write (Environment.NewLine);
                    break;
                case HtmlTagId.P:
                    if (tag.IsEndTag || tag.IsEmptyElement)
                        writer.Write (Environment.NewLine);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return writer.ToString ();
}
```